# Iphone mobile html add to home screen not working

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari, iphone-standalone-web-app

Apparently i've screwed something up! After adding to home screen, I try to open the "app" and instead of using the iPhone rendering system with standalone mode etc, safari is opening it! It was working fine before, does anyone know what this could be?

Using JQM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta names="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />
```